# Python - create an arbitrary number of lists to store all values in a column

Tags: python

I have csv files in which the number of columns are not constant. For each column, I am trying to store all values in that column into a separate list so that I can count the number of recurring values. I have written some code to do this but, it does not seem to `append` into a list well enough.

Sample input is `love hurt hit`. 
My input is a csv file with a varible number of rows and a variable number of columns. It keeps changing for a different csv file. Say one file has 3 columns and the next file has 20 columns. Yes and no are the values which are present under all those columns. The occurrence of those values is random. What I want to do is extract all the values in each individual column, and append them to a list. So, once I exit the for loop, I would ideally like to see all values in a given column; not the last value nor each value printed one below the other.

When I append all the values, it should be `['love', 'yes' 'no', 'yes' ......]` where `yes` and `no` are values under the column of `love`.
Instead, I have each value printed on a new line such as:

`['love']`

`['yes']`

....

This is what I have so far. Please help!

```
a,b,c = [],[],[]
headings = []
allCols = []

def getColCount(currLine):
    return len(currLine)    

# Open the file and read it
with open(filename1, 'r') as f1:

 csvlines = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')

 for lineNum, line in enumerate(csvlines):
      colCount = getColCount(line)               
      allCols = [[] for x in range(0, colCount)]         

      a.append(line[0])            # this prints like I want it to - in series

      for i in range(0, colCount):

           allCols[i].append(line[i])   # this doesn't

      print ','.join(allCols[2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exchange rows and columns, `zip` is useful. A simple example:

```
>>> data = [["a", "b", "c"], # header row
            [1, 2, 3], # data rows
            [4, 5, 6], 
            [7, 8, 9]]
>>> swap = list(zip(*data))
>>> print(swap)
[('a', 1, 4, 7), # first column
 ('b', 2, 5, 8), # second column
 ('c', 3, 6, 9)] # third column
```

Note that, per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

> The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

Comment: My input is a csv file with a varible number of rows and a variable number of columns. It keeps changing for a different csv file. Say one file has 3 columns and the next file has 20 columns. `Yes` and `no` are the values which are present under all those columns. The occurrence of those values is random. What I want to do is extract all the values in each individual column, and append them to a list.  So, once I exit the for loop, I would ideally like to see all values in a given column; not the last value nor each value printed one below the other.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I am saying that if you take all your rows for a file, as lists, and `zip` them, that will give you a tuple for each column. In my example, `"a"` is like your `"love"` and the numbers are like your `yes` and `no`.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was how do I extract each column from the final list? Your `swap` variable contains all the columns. Now, how can I store each column into a separate variable?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is split the line into an array of each word and then add that to the list. Let's say that your file is 'data.csv'.

What you can do is read the file with:

```
finalData = []
fileHandler = open('data.csv', r)
#Read the lines from the file
for line in fileHandler.readlines():
    #Split the line by comma
    lineArr = line.split(',')
    for i in range(len(lineArr)):
        #Strip any whitespace from the lines
        lineArr[i] = lineArr[i].replace(" ", "")
    #Add the data to the final array
    finalData.append(lineArr)
```

This is a pretty simple way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

another method is to use pandas. its read_csv functionality should just split it into columns for you straightaway, and then summing up should be trivial from there (collections.Counter on each column).

Comment: I tried to use pandas but, I don't think I can  that module project for the project I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

how about using dictionaries to track it all instead.

```
import csv

columns_and_values = {}

with open('my_file') as f1:
        csvlines = csv.reader(f1)
        for line in csvlines:
                line_index_counter = 1
                for value in line:
                        column_value_combo = str(line_index_counter)+"|"+value
                        if column_value_combo in columns_and_values.keys():
                                columns_and_values[column_value_combo]+=1
                        else:
                                columns_and_values[column_value_combo]=1
                        line_index_counter += 1

from pprint import pprint

pprint(columns_and_values)
```